# Move to few point with CAKeyframeAnimation

Tags: objective-c, cakeyframeanimation

I have code :

```
NSMutableArray * pathArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CGPoint currentPoint = CGPointMake(xp, yp);
[pathArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: currentPoint]];

NSMutableArray * pathArray = [algorithm CreatePath];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.values = pathArray;
pathAnimation.path = path;
pathAnimation.duration = 1.0;
[self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

And in path array I have few CGPoints wrapped in NSValue. But when animation go its only move from first to last coordinate? Why it not use other points?

New code:

```
-(void)MoveBallWithAlgorithm:(CGPoint)start end:(CGPoint)end;
{
    FindWayAlgorithm *algorithm = [[FindWayAlgorithm alloc]init];
    algorithm.LX = algorithm.LY = self.columns;

    [algorithm CreateBoard:self.fieldsArray];
    [algorithm FindWay:start end:end];
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    NSMutableArray * pathArray = [algorithm CreatePath];

       @try
    {
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.x, self.firstBall.ballCoordinates.y);
        for (NSValue * pointValue in pathArray) {
            CGPoint point = [pointValue CGPointValue];
            Field* field = [self FindFieldWithPoint:point];
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, field.ballCoordinates.x, field.ballCoordinates.y);
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException* ex)
    {
        NSLog(@"Bug captured when move ball with algorithm: %@ %@",ex, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }
    CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    pathAnimation.duration = 2.0;
    pathAnimation.path = path;
    [pathAnimation setDelegate:self];
    [self.firstBall.ballLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"position"];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{

    NSInteger firstBallIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:self.firstBall];
    NSInteger secondBallIndex = [self.fieldsArray indexOfObject:self.secondBall];
    self.ballFrom = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:firstBallIndex];
    self.ballTo = [self.fieldsArray objectAtIndex:secondBallIndex];
    self.ballTo.ballLayer = self.ballFrom.ballLayer;
    CGPoint endPt = CGPointMake(self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.x,self.secondBall.ballCoordinates.y);

    self.ballTo.ballLayer.frame = CGRectMake(endPt.x, endPt.y, self.ballSize, self.ballSize);
    self.ballFrom.ballLayer = nil;
    [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:firstBallIndex withObject:self.ballFrom];
    [self.fieldsArray replaceObjectAtIndex:secondBallIndex withObject:self.ballTo];
    self.firstBall = nil;
    self.secondBall = nil;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code formatting in your question, and add the code that adds lines or curves to the path.

Comment: Which of methods I should use to my animation move from few points, one to another ? I am beginner in animation :/

Answer (score 4):

My problem is resolved. I add:

```
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
```

Now my layer not back to first position ;)

Comment: Hey I just have to say that I've been searching forever for this answer.  Thank you SO MUCH for posting this.

Answer (score 2):

The `CAKeyframeAnimation` documentation states:

> Specifying a `path` overrides the `values` property.

so you should not set `pathAnimation.path` if you want to set the keyframe values with
`pathAnimation.values = pathArray`.

I tested it with a simple label and the following code:

```
NSArray * pathArray = @[
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10., 10.)],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100., 10.)],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10., 100.)],
    [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(10., 10.)],
];

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.values = pathArray;
pathAnimation.duration = 5.0;
[self.label.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"position"];
```

Comment: @netmajor: I tried your code and after removing `pathAnimation.path = path` it animated an object through all positions in the `pathArray`.

Comment: @netmajor: Your `pathArray` contains only one point (the current point), not multiple points.

Comment: No, I only show You how I add object. I add other values in other piece of code ;)

Comment: @netmajor: Then I have no idea. It worked on my small test app.

Comment: In your test what do You use ad ballLayer ? Becouse Ichange my code ad above and get error : void CGPathAddLineToPoint(CGMutablePathRef, const CGAffineTransform *, CGFloat, CGFloat): no current point.

Comment: @netmajor: I suggested to *remove* `pathAnimation.path = path` and assign only `pathAnimation.values = pathArray`. You have done the opposite!

Comment: I have added my code, please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @netmajor: Did you make any progress?

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking. I update code, now my first animation works almost. In first method animation move on all points, but go back at first point at end :/ In second method animation move from this first point to last, but it not go threw all point, only first and second. Why when I set rectangle to frame it not only show in last point, but move from first to last ?